# Extracting the upper and lower limits from a forecast function

Tags: r, forecasting

I am trying to plot a graph with the lower and upper limits. Since I am combining 2 forecast models, I am unsure how to get the values of the lower and upper limit in a matrix.

Basically, I want to get the same plot that we get when we use a normal plot function i.e, forecast values with upper and lower ranges.

This is the code I am trying:

```
df <- Base_df[1:39, ] 
Test_df <- Base_df[40:45,]

fcast <- matrix(NA,nrow=6,ncol=ncol(df))
upper <- matrix(NA,nrow=6,ncol=ncol(df))
lower <- matrix(NA,nrow=6,ncol=ncol(df))

for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  fcets <- forecast(ets(df[,i],ic='aicc', seasonal.periods=6, level =95))
  fcar <- forecast(arima(df[,i]),h=12/2, level =95)
    #combining the values from both the forecasts 
    fcast[,i] <- (0.5*fcets$mean + 0.5*fcar$mean)
    #To get the values of upper limit
    upper[,i] <- 0.5*fcets$upper+0.5*fcar$upper
    #To get the values of lower limit
    lower[,i]<- 0.5*fcets$lower+0.5*fcar$lower
    } 

for(i in 1:10){
  plot(df[,i], type="l", col ="blue", main = colnames(Test_df)[i])
  lines(fcast[,i], col='red')
  lines(upper[,i])
  lines(lower[,i])
}
```

Error:

```
Error in upper[, i] <- 0.5 * fc1$upper[, 1] + 0.5 * fc2$upper[, 1] : 
 number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Please note that df is a matrix with 10 coulmns and 39 rows and all these columns denote the data of individual product.

I understand that upper and lower matrix must be defined in a different way. Can someone help me with how can it be correctly coded?

Comment: What is `Test_df`? Please add output of **`dput(Test_df)`** as an edit to your question.

Comment: Hey, added df and Test_df

Answer (score 0):

Why not use build-in functionality ([fable](https://github.com/tidyverts/fable))

```
library(fable)
library(tsibble)
library(tsibbledata)
library(lubridate)
aus_retail %>%
  filter(
    State %in% c("New South Wales", "Victoria"),
    Industry == "Department stores"
  ) %>% 
  fable::model(
    ets = ETS(box_cox(Turnover, 0.3))
  ) %>%
  fable::forecast(level = 95) %>% 
  autoplot(filter(aus_retail, year(Month) > 2010))
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, but seems like I cannot use this code: ```Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘fable’ is not available (for R version 3.5.2)```. Is it possible to do something such with the code I have produced?

Comment: You have to install the package from github `# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("tidyverts/fable")`